# mysql SELECT distinct row from col1 WHERE col2=x

Tags: php, mysql, distinct

Im trying to select distinct names from 'Specifically' but only where col Type  = a specific value.

For example I have

```
rowID    Type   Specifically
1        cat    Ocicat
2        cat    Bombay
3        cat    Bombay
4        cat    Bengal
5        cat    Savannah
6        dog    Collie
7        dog    Keeshond
8        dog    Pug
9        dog    Keeshond
10       dog    Pug
11       dog    Doberman
12       Horse  n/a
```

And I want to read out something like

```
type=cat and specific=Bengal
type=cat and specific=Bombay
type=cat and specific=Ocicat
type=cat and specific=Savannah
```

I currently have this but its giving me 'Undefined index: Type'

```
$Result = mysql_query("select distinct Specifically from pet_table WHERE Type='cat' ORDER BY Specifically asc ");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Result)) 
{
PRINT("type=".$row['Type']." and specific=".$row['Specifically']."<BR>");
}
```

I would also like to do something like where Type is not cat OR dog OR horse... ect

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want GROUP BY

```
SELECT Type, Specifically FROM pet_table
  WHERE Type='cat'
  GROUP BY Specifically
  ORDER BY Specifically asc
```

Comment: he needs `Type` column as well

Answer (score 2):

The index doesn't exist because you're not selecting it. Include `Type` in your `SELECT` statement to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You get the Undefined Index error, because you are not fetching the `Type` column, but are trying to use it.

Change your query to.

```
select type, distinct Specifically from pet_table 
WHERE Type='cat' ORDER BY Specifically asc
```

Secondly, if you want Type not cat or dog or horse, you can use the `NOT IN` clause.

Finally, please don't use MySQL as it is not maintained and is deprecated. Consider using, MySQLi, or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting this error is because you're not selecting `Type`.

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `Specifically`,`Type` from `pet_table` WHERE `Type`='cat' ORDER BY `Specifically` ASC");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    echo "The type is {$row['Type']} and it is specifically a {$row['Specifically']}
}
```